# Google Sign in xamarin.forms Android - Error:disallowed_useragent

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, google-oauth

I am trying to implement Google sign-in in my app but I am facing the disallowed_useragent error. From research, I believe Google no longer supports Webview. I haven't found any suitable solution to this error though. Does anyone know how I can fix this? Below is my code

**GoogleLoginRenderer.cs**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Login), typeof(GoogleSignIn2.Droid.GoogleLoginRenderer))]
namespace GoogleSignIn2.Droid
{
    public class GoogleLoginRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
        public GoogleLoginRenderer()
        {
            var activity = this.Context as Activity;
            var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator(
                clientId: "",
                clientSecret: "",
                scope: "openid",
                authorizeUrl: new Uri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"),
                redirectUrl: new Uri("http://www.posworx.co.za/"),
                accessTokenUrl: new Uri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"),
                getUsernameAsync: null
                );

            auth.Completed += async (s, e) =>
            {
                if (e.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    string emailAddress = string.Empty;
                    var token = e.Account.Properties["access_token"].ToString();
                    var expiresIn = Convert.ToDouble(e.Account.Properties["expires_in"]);
                    var expireDate = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(expiresIn);
                    var request = new OAuth2Request("GET", new Uri("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo"), null, e.Account);
                    var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();

                    var obj = JObject.Parse(response.GetResponseText());
                    var id = obj["id"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                    var name = obj["name"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");

                    App.NavigateToVerified();
                }
                else
                {
                    App.InvalidLogin();

                }
            };

            activity.StartActivity(auth.GetUI(activity));


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: On a device and yes I have chrome installed. I am using Xamarin.Auth. How can I add the Chrome Custom Tab ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `isUsingNativeUI` param to `true` (the current default is `false`)

```
    //  true    - Native UI
    //            Android - [Chrome] Custom Tabs
    //            iOS - Safari View Controller
    //  false   - embedded WebViews
    //            Android - WebView
    //            iOS - UIWebView or WKWebView
```

i.e.:

```
OAuth2Authenticator auth = new OAuth2Authenticator 
(
    ~~~~
    isUsingNativeUI: true
    ~~~~
);
```

re: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth